# How to write the AR polynomial for a model containing a constant?

Tags: time-series, self-study, autoregressive

I'm  working on an exercise,

> Consider the autoregressive time series model $$y_t=c+\frac{1}{3}y_{t-1}-\frac{1}{2}y_{t-2}+\epsilon_t,\tag{$\ast$}$$ where $\epsilon_t$ is white noise with variance $1$. Write $(\ast)$ in compact form using the backward shift operator $B$. Show $(\ast)$ is causal.

I see I can write $(\ast)$ as
$$ \epsilon_t = \phi(B)y_t-c, \text{ where } \phi(x)=1-\frac{1}{3}x+\frac{1}{2}x^2,$$
but I don't know how to include $c$ in $\phi$ or how to do a causality test without having the whole expression in the form $\epsilon_t=\phi(B)y_t$.

Could someone give me a pointer?

Comment: It's pretty easy to drop the $c$ term by taking out the unconditional mean (if process is stationary and time invariant $E[y]$ exists). Take expectations on both sides. Solve for $E[y]$. Define $x_t = y_t - E[y]$. Substitute back into original equation. You'll have an AR(2) in $x_t$ but with no c term. (It sounds like that's what you're looking for?)

Comment: @MatthewGunn I get $\epsilon_t=\phi(B)x_t$ with the same $\phi$ as in the OP. I can see intuitively why shifting a series vertically shouldn't affect properties like causality. Would you say that in general this sort of constant can just be ignored when doing an autoregressive polynomial causality test?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One can rewrite
$$y_t=c+\frac{1}{3}y_{t-1}-\frac{1}{2}y_{t-2}+\epsilon_t$$
as
$$\left[y_t-\frac{6}{7}c\right]=\frac{1}{3}\left[y_{t-1}-\frac{6}{7}c\right]-\frac{1}{2}\left[y_{t-2}-\frac{6}{7}c\right]+\epsilon_t,$$
since
$$\frac{6}{7}c-\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{6}{7}c+\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{6}{7}c=c$$
and hence get rid of the constant. To connect with the comment from [Matthew Gunn](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/97925/matthew-gunn), the expectation of the stationary mean (assuming it exists$^1$) is
$$\mathbb E[Y_t] = \frac{6}{7}c$$

---

$¹$ And it does since the complex roots of $\Phi(B)$ are within the unit circle.

Comment: Typo? $E[y_t] = \frac{6}{7}c$.

Comment: @MatthewGunn: Thank you for pointing out the typo.